# Apache Airflow - installation issue : sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) no schema has been selected to create in

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I'm trying to install Airflow on Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine with PostgreSQL DB which I have done previously without any problems.

I'm carefully following Airflow installation, in DB setup part:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html

I ran into issues after trying to initialize db with:

```
airflow db init
```

gave me:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName)
> no schema has been selected to create in

It says:

> Also note that since SqlAlchemy does not expose a way to target a
> specific schema in the database URI, you may want to set a default
> schema for your role with a SQL statement similar to
>
> ```
> ALTER ROLE username SET search_path = airflow, foobar;
> ```

I'm assuming I have to use this since tutorial doesn't state which schema airflow db uses:

```
ALTER ROLE airflow_user SET search_path = airflow;
```

Did that, reloaded psql conf, rebooted DB server, whole machine - same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to DB account with:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Go to psql prompt:

```
psql
```

Connect to airflow db:

```
\c airflow_db
```

Run:

```
ALTER ROLE airflow_user SET search_path = airflow, public;
```

Now run

```
airflow init db
```

It should initialize db fine.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to DB account and start psql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

At psql create airflow schema for the airflow user:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS airflow AUTHORIZATION airflow;
```

Alter airflow user

```
ALTER ROLE airflow SET search_path = airflow, public;
```

Exit psql and set alchemy variables:

```
export AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN="postgresql://airflow:you_passowrd@localhost:5432/airflow?options=-csearch_path%3Dairflow"
export AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_SCHEMA="airflow"

Initialize airflow db:
airflow db init
```